# Custom Control Entry not getting set the Place Holder Color Bindable Property

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a  custom control its  a date picker but the PlaceHolderColor is not being set and not having affect.

```
public Color PlaceHolderColorText
{
     get => 
     (Color)GetValue(PlaceHolderColorProperty);
     set => SetValue(PlaceHolderColorProperty,
     value);
}

 public static readonly BindableProperty
 PlaceHolderColorProperty = 
BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PlaceHolderColor), 
typeof(Color), 
typeof(DateTimePicker2),Color.Black , BindingMode.TwoWay, 
 propertyChanged: OnPlaceHodlerColorChanged);
```

I am creating dynamic entrys as such

```
public Entry _dayEntry { get; private set; } = new Entry() { 
TabIndex = 0, Placeholder = "dd", Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric, 
WidthRequest = 60, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start };
 
public Entry _monthEntry { get; private set; } = new Entry() { 
TabIndex = 1, Placeholder = "MM", Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric, 
WidthRequest = 60, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start };
```

But I am unsure as to what I need here to get the value to apply to the entry properly

```
public static void OnPlaceHodlerColorChanged(BindableObject 
bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
        var test = newValue;      
     ///do something with new but dont no what.
}
```

I am adding my entrys like this to the children of the stack

```
public DateTimePicker2()
{
    BindingContext = this;

    _dayEntry.TextChanged += _dayEntry_TextChanged;
    _monthEntry.TextChanged += _monthEntry_TextChanged;
    _yearEntry.TextChanged += _yearEntry_TextChanged;
    _dayEntry.TextColor= TextColor;
    _monthEntry.TextColor= TextColor;
    _yearEntry.TextColor= TextColor;
    _dayEntry.PlaceholderColor = PlaceHolderColor;
    _monthEntry.PlaceholderColor = PlaceHolderColor;
    _yearEntry.PlaceholderColor = PlaceHolderColor;
    _hourEntry.TextColor= TextColor;
    _minsEntry.TextColor= TextColor;
    SelectedDateChanged +=DateTimePicker2_SelectedDateChanged;
    Content = new StackLayout()
    {
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            Children =
            {    _datePicker,
                 _timePicker,
                _monthEntry,
                _dayEntry,                    
                _yearEntry,
                _hourEntry,
                _minsEntry,
                _ampmPicker,
                iconButton

 }
};
```

I am a bit perplexed as to what to do to get the event to register the place holder color to correct entry you will see am doing here.

```
_dayEntry.PlaceholderColor = PlaceHolderColor;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Initial `BindableProperty` correctly , the name should be same as the property .

   ```
   public Color PlaceHolderColor
   {
        get => 
     (Color)GetValue(PlaceHolderColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(PlaceHolderColorProperty,
     value);
   }

   public static readonly BindableProperty PlaceHolderColorProperty = 
   BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PlaceHolderColor), 
   typeof(Color), 
   typeof(DateTimePicker2),Color.Black , BindingMode.TwoWay, 
   propertyChanged: OnPlaceHodlerColorChanged);
   ```
2. `OnPlaceHodlerColorChanged` event triggers while the proerty value gets changed,  so you need to manually set it on Entry.PlaceholderColor .

   ```
   public static void OnPlaceHodlerColorChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
   {
        Color test = newValue as Color;      

        var control = (DateTimePicker2)bindable;
        control._dayEntry.PlaceholderColor = test ;
        control._monthEntry.PlaceholderColor = test ;
        control._yearEntry.PlaceholderColor = test ;
   }
   ```

Comment: Sorry what do u mean the second porperty

Comment: Also I cannot access _dayEntry in here as this is a static method

Comment: Check my update .

Comment: Getting this on color Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0077 The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('Color' is a non-nullable value type

Comment: Which line causes the error ?

Comment: Try `control._dayEntry.PlaceholderColor = newValue ;`

Comment: JUST MEANT to add thanks thats that worked a treat for me when i did it